# Insert Into MySql Database using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to insert the data from form to the database using ajax. When I run it, it only displays index.php code and do nothing.I am not able to find out the error. So, please help me to run this code.

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter Text"> 
<button id="submit" onClick="js()" type="button"> Submit</button>

<script> 
function js() {

var name = document.getElementById("name").value ;


$.ajax({

type:'POST',
data: name,
url:"insert.php",
success:function(result){
alert(success); 
}

}); 
}

</script>
</body>



</html>
```

insert.php

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'sample');
if($_POST['name']){
$name=$_POST['name'];   
$q= "insert into test ('$name')";
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $q);
if($query){
echo 'inserted';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What is your table structure for `test`? If more than 1 column, you would need to specify the column name. You could also do `$query = mysqli_query($connection, $q) or die(mysqli_error($connection));` to debug

Comment: You need to include `jquery` in your `index.php` file. One resource could be [this](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery)

Answer (score 0):

If your table structure as given below :

```
id int PK (Auto_increment)
name varchar(30) not null
```

You have to use following code :

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter Text"> 
<button id="submit" onClick="js()" type="button"> Submit</button>
<script> 
function js()
{
    if(document.getElementById("name").value!="")
    {
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value ;
        $.post("insert.php",{name:name},function(data){
            if(data)
            {
                alert(data);
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Cancel.");   
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Enter name.");
        document.getElementById("name").focus();
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

insert.php

```
<?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
    if($_POST['name'])
    {
        $name=$_POST['name'];   
        $q= "insert into test(name) values ('$name')";
        $query = mysqli_query($connection, $q);
        if($query)
        {
            echo 'inserted';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'no inserted';
        }
    }
?>
```

If you have any confusion please let me know.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try below... This may be helpful for you..

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter Text"> 
<button id="submit" onClick="js()" type="button"> Submit</button>

<script> 
function js() {

var name = $("#name").val();

$.ajax({

type:'POST',
data: 'name='+name,
url:"insert.php",
success:function(result){
alert(success); 
}

}); 
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And PHP script is as below.

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'sample');
if($_POST['name']){
$name=$_POST['name'];   
$q= "INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('$name')";
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $q);
if($query){
echo 'inserted';
}
}
?>
```